# Terminals shuts down when launced by specific user

Tags: gnome-terminal, putty

Ubuntu Server 16.04 controlled by vncserver GUI and putty. When launching terminal it shuts down immediately. Similar is happening when I login with my user in putty. After entered password putty shuts down. This don´t happen when logged in with root or other users. So it must have something to do with my users permissions. This all happend when installing vsftpd. Vsftpd is now removed. Same error occur when logging in with Putty which shuts down. How to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: *"This all happend when installing vsftpd"* - it's going to be hard to answer without more information about what you did exactly - it might be caused by a change to the user's login shell, or something you added to a shell configuration file (~/.bashrc, ~/.profile etc.) that is causing the login shell to exit immediately

Comment: I´ve followed this guide from Digital Ocean and used it before on another server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04 . @Steeldriver what should I look for in .bashrc?

Comment: Tried with xterm as well but still stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

It was impossible to find the specific error that caused the shutdown, so this was the aternative way.

**The workaround to solve this is:**

- Back up files in users(the one that causes error) home folder
- Create a new user with admin privileges
- delete old user
- rename the new user with old users username
- paste old users files to new users home folder and change ownership to new user (sudo chown -R NEWUSER: /home/NEWUSER)
- reboot